# Can you divide code using pragma-like directives in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, xcode, code-organization, pragma

I am currently developing a Java tool in eclipse and some files are getting pretty messy. Unfortunately it seems like one cannot spread Java classes over several files, yet I would like to keep my code organized in a some way.

Back when I used Xcode for development, I could use a preprocessor directive called `#pragma mark -` to insert code divisions and `#pragma mark TITLE` to insert a title into the code division overview. See:

[image]

Is there something alike in Java for eclipse? Nevertheless, there is a nice outline view which would be best suited for such a task.

Thanks & Regards

Max

**UPDATE**

I've been made aware that the length of my class may be the key issue here, yet I don't see how I could reduce it. Before carrying on, I should mention that the example above was *just to show the concept* of using the `#pragma mark` directive and has nothing to do with my actual code.

The class is a converter that parses through an RDF/XML file to extract objects from that file so they can be stored in a local `HashSet<>`. Although this code is not fully working, it contains some essential functions and (in my mind) won't get much shorter. See:

[image]

Any help as to how I could organize this in a better and tidier way would be very appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Max

Comment: For the title, you should use Javadoc... and if your class feels like it should be spread over multiple files, you might want to consider whether it should be multiple classes...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make it multiple classes since it is a custom XML parser that needs to untangle the file itself. This means the Class file will be quite long. How should I Javadoc for the title? There is no `@title` tag and if I insert any doc-comment in front of a method using `/** ... */` it doesn't add anything to the overview.

Comment: Not sure what the "overview" is in this case - but just `/** This does something */` would be the normal Java way of doing it. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, to be honest - or what created your screenshot. More context in the question would help a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the "Outline" view of the eclipse IDE. `/** This does something */` adds information for when you generate your Javadoc, but does not really help organize code when coding it. Or maybe I am using it wrong?

Comment: Hmm - that looks very different to the outline view I'm used to. But yes, it appears the Javadoc summary isn't included in there. If the names are well chosen, I wouldn't expect that to be too important though - the summary will appear when you try to autocomplete, for example. Do you spend much of your time looking in the outline?

Comment: Due to the length of my class I spend some time scrolling through the Outline. Then I remembered that there was a feature in Xcode to help me and I was wondering if there is something similar for eclipse. I try to choose my method names so they are intuative, but some visual aid would definitely help.

Comment: Again, it sounds like the size of your class is the primary issue here - that will cause a number of different problems in terms of maintenance, readability etc. As I said before, some more context would really help - "it's a custom XML parser that needs to untangle the file itself" doesn't really explain much.

Comment: Ok, I'll add an update to my question.